# What software can I use test the performance of my system?

Tags: 11.10, software-recommendation, 64-bit, performance

I installed Ubuntu (11.10 64bit) to my new laptop (Asus A53E-XT4), and would like to test capabilities, especially it's 6GB's of RAM.

Is there any software in the Software Center (or on the web), that can help me do this?

I tried running a couple of applications, but the RAM hasn't even passed to 3GB mark!

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend that you check out the phoronix test suite. You can install it by entering the following in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install phoronix-test-suite
```

Here is a quick run down on beginning steps in running the quake4 test.

Some of the tests require a large amount of hard drive space, and could take a considerable amount of time to download the quake 4 test took over 10 minutes on a usually decent High-Speed connection, so make sure you're aware of this.

```
phoronix-test-suite --list-available-tests
```

You will see a ton of choices. I chose to install the quake 4 test in this example.

```
phoronix-test-suite install pts/quake4
```

This will pull down all the test and it's dependency files as seen in the image below:

[image]

Once it's finished downloading, you will then just enter the following in order to run the test:

```
phoronix-test-suite run pts/quake4
```

There might be more specific results you're looking for, so just look through the available tests and suites and I'm sure you'll find something that suits you.

Please check out this link [here](http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/?k=documentation) for further documentation on how to use the suite.